# Rails Installer Git vs Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I signed up at the Github website and downloaded the desktop client a few months ago. I used that to sync up changes I made on my computer to the github repo for my Rails project.

Now I've installed rails on a new computer with the rails installer and git along with it when given the option. Then I provided my name and email address with the git configuration afterward.

Does this mean I can now push my rails project using the command line? Is this git the same as using github?

Answer (score 3):

Think of git and github as mail app (i.e. Outlook) and web service (i.e. Gmail)

Does this mean that mail application is same? No. (So these git versions could be different, but most of time git support same commands).

Does this mean that you can check email with your gmail credentials? Yes. (Using your credentials for github, you can push code)

All git staff where to push, branches, tags and so on is saved in repository/.git folder. So when you try to push, git will get this information from there.
But, you actually need to add your new ssh public key to github.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If you have the github repo set for your upstream commits it should be fine. Here is [a link to setting up](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) github access locally. Sorry to provide a broad link but without OS my comments might not be useful.

Comment: I'm working in Windows. I already have a github account. And now I have git as a subfolder under C:\Railsinstaller.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes